# C#: Sending email to a list of recipients in a loop and update UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, email, user-interface

I've created a Windows From application (.Net 4.5) and using a loop I send emails to different recipients (a listview populated with the email addresses and checkboxes);

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView_addresses.Items.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        ListView_addresses.Items[i].Selected = true;
        ///////////////////////////////
        //the code for smtp properties
        //////////////////////////////
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        ListView_addresses.Items[i].Checked = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        ListView_addresses.Items[i].Checked = false;
    }
}
```

if email can be sent it ticks the checkbox and if it cant doesn't.

The problem is that the main UI is blocked during execution without refreshing the changes in the listview.

What should I do?

Comment: you can use TPL, threading or an backgroundworker. I prefer Backgroundworker. You have to visualize the progress in your main thread.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean the code for implementation

Answer (score 0):

`SmtpServer.Send(mail);` does not return anything if an email has failed or delivered because SMTP is a stateless protocol. So you need to check the status of the email after some time, for example, after 6 hours in the POP3 account from which you have sent the email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the mail function in a separate thread in order to not block the ui thread, or you can use async function. 
One solution is to use background worker. Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use "Async - await" concept to make this work. While the process sends the email, the UI will still be responsive.
For more info, kindly refer the link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Example with a Backgroundworker:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListView_addresses.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {

                //ListView_addresses.Items[i].Selected = true;
                ///////////////////////////////
                //the code for smtp properties
                //////////////////////////////
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                //ListView_addresses.Items[i].Checked = true;
                ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(0, new SmtpResult { Index = i, Checked = true, Selected = true });
            }
            catch
            {
                ListView_addresses.Items[i].Checked = false;
                ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress(0, new SmtpResult { Index = i, Checked = false, Selected = true });
            }
        }
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = (SmtpResult)e.UserState;
        ListView_addresses.Items[result.Index].Checked = result.Checked;
        ListView_addresses.Items[result.Index].Selected = result.Selected;
    }
}

public class SmtpResult
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```